# I want to solve this differential equation in $ℂ$

Tags: complex-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

I want to solve this **differential equation** in $ℂ$:
$$(1-2^{1-s})f′(s)=2^{1-s}(ln2)f(s)$$
where $f$ is an analytic function for all $s=α+iβ∈ℂ$ with $0<α<1$ and has infinitely many zeros in the strip.

Comment: I'm not sure you can use logarithmic differentiation of complex functions. If you can: $$\left[\log f(s)\right]' = \cfrac{f'(s)}{f(s)} \implies \\ f(s) = 2 \exp \left(\int \cfrac{2^{1-s}}{1-2^{1-s}} \text{d}s\right)$$

Comment: @DanielR: But the variable is complex, then we need a contour to make the integration.

Comment: Right, and that's out of my league really. But I hope and believe that you can use the analyticity to argue that a complex antiderivative exists (check out http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antiderivative_(complex_analysis) ). But I'm not sure and we'd better wait for one of the real experts to come to rescue!

Comment: @DanielR: Maybe we can restrict $s$ to $(0,1)$ as a real number and then we proceed by using the identity theorem.

Comment: Yes, that might be a good idea and a neat one as well! But I can't verify that it's a watertight procedure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Since doubts remain in some circles I replace the previous hint by a complete answer)

The given ODE is a homogeneous linear differential equation of first order. The standard way of solving such an equation is to introduce a new unknown function $s\mapsto g(s)$ by writing $f(s):=e^{g(s)}$. This leads to the mere quadrature problem
$$g'(s)={2\log 2\over\exp(s\log2)-2}=:h(s)\qquad(0<{\rm Re}(s)<1)\ .$$
Note that the right hand side $h(s)$ is analytic in the strip $S:\>0<{\rm Re}(s)<1$. Since $S$ is simply connected it has  analytic primitives $g:\ S\to{\mathbb C}$ there. In the case at hand we obtain formally
$$g(s)=\log(2-e^{s\log2})-s\log2+C\ .\tag{1}$$
When $s\in S$ then the points $2-e^{s\log2}$ lie in an open disk of radius $2$ with center $2$; therefore  the principal value ${\rm Log}$ can serve as well-defined $\log$ in $(1)$.

From $(1)$ we obtain
$$f(s)=e^{g(s)}=C'\ (2e^{-s\log2}-1)$$
as general solution of the original problem.

Comment: @ Christian Blatter: But $f(s)$ has infinitely many zeros in the strip.

Comment: @AR1: See my edit. I don't think that any nontrivial solution $f$ has even a single zero in the strip $0<{\rm Re}(s)<1$.

Comment: Shouldn't one worry about monodromy?

Comment: @ automaton: Ye, this is my conserne too.

Comment: @automaton: See the complete solution.